# Question about name mismatches

Tags: discussion, canonical-questions

I just approved a first question, but I had an hard time deciding what to do.

Basically it's a more of the same "name on document A does not match name on document B". I think it's a duplicate as we have tons of questions about this, but at the end of the day I couldn't find an exact match as:

1. There seem to be an infinite versions of this question. Missing middle name, missing last name, different abbreviations, second name is 28039 characters long, missing the name of the last father of the second brother of some distant relative penguin...seems everything is possible when it comes to names.
2. Due to point 1 and due to me not being a lawyer, I feel really uncomfortable at pointing which is duplicate to which. The one I accepted, for example, says that the boarding pass miss the last name. Which by the way is oddly written without the upper cased initial.

So, due to point 1 and point 2, I was wondering if

- We should just let it be decided case by case by and if someone feel confident enough to take a guess (and sooner or later give the wrong information and cause the OP some huge problem)

or

- Someone feel brave enough to post a community answer covering all possible cases (if possible),close all those future questions as duplicates and point to the community answer

or

- Stick to a precompiled answer like "Usually it's not a big issue as long as blah blah blah, but we are not lawyers and every company/embassy/whatever has its own rules so we strongly suggest to send them a mail just to play safe"

<sub>(which, by the way, makes me wonder why people do not do it as the first thing. I can understand asking a relative that you have at immediate reach, but coming to SE, opening an account, posting the question, coming back from time to time to see if someone answered you...why not simply send an email to the company? O_o)</sub>

Comment: There are and will be an infinite variety of name questions, because there are essentially no rules when it comes to names: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: I think a canonical with the precompiled answer #3 is the way to go and covers the based. Too many variants of this question appearing.

Answer (score 2):

A single canonical must be created covering all the typical cases and all future questions should be closed as a dupe, no exceptions. Feel free to start one :)

Comment: No way, IANAL :-D